# non-static method cannot be referenced by static context

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

So I have a program that I'm trying to run which plots a line, square,  that takes in the command line arguments say l 5 s 4 c 6. With this I plot out the shapes using a `2Darray`. In my program I have a driver class, a `char2D` class(my class that handles the `2darray`), and `myLine`. `myLine` derives from `char2D` using inheritance.

My question is this:
Why do I get a compiling error cannot be referenced from static context? Would I have to move the switch statement that parses the command line arguments to a different method? If so would I have to do anything other than just cut the statement into a new method?

**Here's my compiling error.**

> /home/miguel/School/project3 v2/driver.java:11:
>   error: non-static method myLine(int) cannot be referenced from a static context
>               myLine( size1 );
>               ^

Here's my **driver** class (**Ignore the commented out sections as I have to fix these since I rewrote my program**):

```
public class driver {

public static void main(String[] args ){
String type = args[0];
int size;

switch (type.toLowerCase().charAt( 0 )) {
    case 'l': 
        int size1;
        size1 = Integer.parseInt( args[1] );
        myLine( size1 );
        break;
//  case 's' : 
//      size2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
//      mySquare( size );
//      break; 
//  case 'c' : 
//      size3 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
//      myCube( size );
//      break;
}

}




}

}
public static void myLine( int size ){                  
        myLine( size );
    }
    // System.out.print( "*");                  // don't need to print in here

    //myLine(int size); 
//  public int mySquare( int size ) {
    //for (i = 0; i < size ; i++)
//      mySquare( size );

}

//  public void myCube( int size ){                                     // z will be x but only have the length of it 
    //z = size + .5
    //  myCube(size )
//  }
```

Here's my **char2D** class

```
public class char2D {

protected int width; protected int height; protected char char2D[][];


public char2D( int width, int height ){                     //line              
    this.width = width; 
    this.height = height;
    char2D = new array[height][width];

}
public void grow( int width, int height ){              //note width and height are changing in this method
     this.height += height;
     this.width += width;
     char2D = new array[this.height][this.width];

}

public void plot( int x1, int y1 ){
    char2D[y1][x1] = '*';


}

public static toString( char2D )
    return char2D.toString();
}
```

Here's my myLine class:

```
public class myLine extends char2D{
private int size1; 

public myLine(int size1){
    super( size1, 1 );
    this.size1 = size1;
    plotLine();
    }
private void plotLine(){
    for( int i = 0; i < size1 ; i++){
        plot( 0 , i );



    }

}

}
```

Comment: Change `public void myLine( int size )` to `public static void myLine( int size )`

Comment: I was going to give you the benefit of the doubt on one or two of those compilation errors, but you've got a whole host of them which makes formatting your code *difficult*.  Please post *compilable* code.  At this point, I'm not entirely clear what it is you're doing with `myLine`, as it would only ever call itself.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is myLine() method, you should change:

```
public void myLine(int size)
```

to

```
public static void myLine(int size)
```

Static methods are managed differently than regular methods, because they are in a static context.

Here is some information that will help you better understand this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

By the way, if you want better, quicker responses, you should remove remarked source code when possible.

Comment: To give a quick explanation, a static method is one that belongs to the class as a whole. It's there for you to call even if you don't instantiate a `new myLine()`. Non-static methods belong to a specific object - one instance of myLine. They don't exist until you actually instantiate a `new` object. That's why you're getting the error - you're trying to reference a method that belongs to an instance of myLine when you haven't yet created one.

Comment: Ah sorry about that. Will keep that in mind next time and thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the compile error because you're trying to call `driver#myLine(int)` (which is not a static method) from within `driver#main(String[])` (which is a static method).  The simple fix is simply to change the method signature of `driver#myLine(int)` to:

```
public static void myLine( int size ){
```

Comment: did this and got 3 more errors :

/home/miguel/School/project3/driver.java:30: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 }
 ^
/home/miguel/School/project3/driver.java:31: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 public static void myLine( int size ){               
               ^
/home/miguel/School/project3/driver.java:33: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  }
  ^
3 errors
[Finished in 5.2s with exit code 1]

Answer (score 0):

Your naming convention is wrong!

Your closing blocks, methods class braces are not proper!

removed commented code for more readability.

and also you need to change your `myLine` method to class method if you want to call it from static method.

you can change your code as below

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String type = args[0];
    int size;

    switch (type.toLowerCase().charAt(0)) {
    case 'l':
        int size1;
        size1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        myLine(size1);
        break;
    }

}

public static void myLine(int size) {
    myLine(size);
}
```